# Serialisation and timed web tokens in python flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, flask, serialization

Hi I am struggling to understand the following example.

I want to add functionality for a user to reset password for my website.

As a lot of sites do I want to send a token to the users email that will let them reset their password.

I am following a guide that suggests using a python module called `itsdangerous`.

I have been given the following code as a simple example from the tutorial to understand how the module works before deploying to my website:

```
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer
s = Serializer('secret_key',30)
token = s.dumps({'usr_id': 1}).decode('utf-8')
s.loads(token)
```

Now if I run this here is what happens:

I use `s` to create a token that allows me to take a dictionary `{'usr_id':1}` then if I run `s.loads(token)` within `30` seconds I can get this dictionary `{'usr_id':1}` back otherwise I get an error.

Can anyone explain (in a simple way for a beginner) what is going on here?

I don't really understand what is happening and I don't see what the `secret_key` argument to the `Serializer` is doing?

Also if someone could explain how this kind of code can help me with allowing users to get an email to reset their password that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So this kind of serialization provided by itsdangerous library is JSON Web Token based. In order to create a JSON Web Token you need a **secret key**, which is a signature to certify that the information tokenized was provided by you and can only be edited with this signature.

A JSON Web Token can be read by anyone but can only be edited by someone who knows the secret key - so you shouldn't tokenize sensitive information like a password, but a user id is ok, which alongside a expiry time set is just enough to check its identity. You must hide your secret key and keep it safe.

A good usage in your case would be to send a expiring token - let's say one day - to the user email, to proof it has authorization to change the password. And after one day it'll be invalid, so you won't compromise your system.

**What is the JSON Web Token structure?**

In its compact form, JSON Web Tokens consist of three parts separated by dots (.), which are:

Header: The header typically consists of two parts: the type of the token, which is JWT, and the signing algorithm being used, such as HMAC SHA256 or RSA.

Payload: The information and the expiry time is held here.

Signature: The signature is used to verify the message wasn't changed along the way, and, in the case of tokens signed with a secret key, it can also verify that the sender of the JWT is who it says it is.

> Therefore, a JWT typically looks like the following. xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz

You can play around seeing what is inside a JWT by pasting it on the link below:
https://jwt.io/

More info on:
https://jwt.io/introduction/